# Incompatible kernel after Ubuntu update

Tags: server, upgrade, kernel

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa) to upgrade my hosted server from 18.04 to 20.04 over ssh. When I rebooted the server at the end of the upgrade I found I could no longer connect via ssh. My hosting provider was really helpful, resurrected my server and sent me the following explanation:

> I found your server down and was not able to boot up due to an incompatible kernel. After reconfiguring your server to use the old kernel version the server started normally.

- Why would a kernel be incompatible?
- Does it matter that I'm using an older kernel?
- Is it possible to upgrade in future without updating the kernel at
  the same time?

As requested below here is the Ubuntu version information:

`$ uname -a`

```
4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`$ lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

`$dpkg -l linux-image | grep ^ii`

...does not return any response

Comment: Could you please provide a little more data? Specifically `uname -a` (for the current kernel version) and `dpkg -l linux-image | grep ^ii` for all installed kernels. Also the output of `lsb_release -a` would help. Thanks.

Comment: Big warning box on that tutorial that it-might-not-work and offering an alternative for DO customers.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks I realise that now and won't attempt it again. I'd be grateful if you can explain what DO stands for?

Comment: DO = Digital Ocean

Comment: @popey Thanks, I've updated my question with the information you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ask your host. It is not something you will see when installing Ubuntu on a desktop or private server.
2. No. As long as the hosting provider provides 18.04 you should be fine.
3. No. When using a hosting provider you should use the operating system that hosting provider provides.

A hosting provider tends to provide a pre configured, known to work, operating system. When you want a new operating system you create it at the console provided by the hosting provider not by upgrading. It is far too risky to do that from command line: as you saw your system is dead if it can not boot. On GCE, AWS and Azure you probably would have lost your instance.

Comment: That was very helpful thank you. I had no idea about any of that and it seems like my provider was very patient with me.